# Display different sidebar based on search results from one category

Tags: categories, search, sidebar

I have a website with a [plant index page](https://sucsforyou.com/plant-index/). It has a custom sidebar using A-Z Listings and a search form that only returns results from the 'plantindex' category.
When using the sidebar search form, say for 'Aloe,' the results page uses the default sidebar instead of the plant index sidebar. [Link to that result on my site.](https://sucsforyou.com/?s=aloe&id=7229&post_type=post)
I would like to know the most efficient way to call the custom plant index sidebar to the search results page when returning the results from the plant index search form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make changes in search.php page and call the sidebar you need to show over there.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I'm thinking I need a dedicated search.php for the plantindex results. Trying to figure out how to call that up in a loop - if results are from cat 'plantindex' show searchplants.php - something like that.

Comment: you need to add conditions in search.php page based on post types